# Laravel 4 not able to query on postgres function

Tags: postgresql, laravel, geolocation, laravel-4

I have a postgres function, distance(), that determines the distance between two points.

```
DECLARE                                                   
    x float = 69.1 * (lat2 - lat1);                           
    y float = 69.1 * (lon2 - lon1) * cos(lat1 / 57.3);        
BEGIN                                                     
    RETURN sqrt(x * x + y * y);                               
END
```

This works fine when executed in Postgres. But now I want to use it in a Laravel 4 search to find all addresses in a radius. Using query builder I have

```
$query->where(\DB::select('select distance(coords,'.$parameters['lat'].','.$parameters['lon'].')') < 9);
```

This should be looking at the coords field in the addresses (ex. '39.606912,-104.881802') and resolve that in the query. It errors saying the column 'coords' does not exist. If I use "addresses"."coords" it then says it cannot find the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually DB::raw() work in these cases and there were some missing commas and quotes in your command

```
$query->where(\DB::select(\DB::raw('select distance(coords,'.$parameters['lat'].','.$parameters['lon'].')')), '<', '9');
```

To make sure Laravel is building it the way you need and that the query it's building will work on your database, use this command to dump your query in log:

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) { 
    Log::info($sql); 
    Log::info($bindings); 
});
```

What your error is saying is that you are missing a FROM, so your query should be:

```
$query->where(
    \DB::select(
        \DB::raw('select distance(addresses.coords,'.$parameters['lat'].','.$parameters['lon'].') FROM addresses')
    )
    , '<', '9'
);
```

But if this is just part of your query and not your whole query, you should not need a FROM, unless you are gettind this info from a different table, which is not already in your main query FROM list.

Comment: I still get the same thing, it is not seeing coords as a column in the addresses table (though it is there)

Comment: Does this select works fine directly in Postgres? `select distance(coords,39.606912,-104.881802)` Plus whatever you have before?

Comment: I didn't mean the function, but the usage of it: the select you are using this function. You gave us just a small part of your query, a simple where, but your query is bigger than that, isn't it? So you have to debug all of it. I just edited my answer to add a method to get the generated query, which should be executable in postgres.

Comment: Well I changed the "addresses"."coords" to "addresses.coords" as that works in other laravel queries. However, now it is saying that "negative substring length not allowed " when I parse the coords field. This indicates that is is simply getting the string "addresses.coords" and not searching the fields in the db. If I do this $query->where((\DB::select(\DB::raw("select cpdistance(".'addresses.coords'.",'39.654872,-104.996809')"))[0]->cpdistance), '<', '9'); then is says missing FROM-clause entry for table "addresses".

Comment: The function needs to receive an imput of form '222.222,111.111' from the addresses coords field.

Comment: You could get the full DB:listen() result and paste it in your  question so people can see your full query, understand what's  happening and try to help.

Comment: I get Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "addresses" LINE 1: select cpdistance(addresses.coords,'39.654872,-104.996809') ^ (SQL: select cpdistance(addresses.coords,'39.654872,-104.996809'))

Comment: This gives the correct result `dd((\DB::select(\DB::raw("select cpdistance('39.606912,-104.881802','39.654872,-104.996809')"))[0]->cpdistance));`

Comment: This errors `$org->whereHas('addresses', function($query)
                        {
                                $query->where((\DB::select(\DB::raw("select cpdistance(".'addresses.coords'.",'39.654872,-104.996809')"))[0]->cpdistance), '<', '9');                            
                        })->get();`

Comment: Just edited to provide some more info about it. But you seriously need to start answering comments the way they were asked, because not understanding what's happening doesn't help to help.